# There is no blank/basic activity

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to add a new blank activity in my project, but I don't know why it is gone from the activities list! Here is the options I get:

[image]

I still need to create multiple blank activities. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the name has changed from "Blank Activity" to "Empty Views Activity".
It is the same as blank activity.